# CMake not defining variables

Tags: c++, cmake

When trying to define project version variables in a config.h for inclusion in source files, CMake doesn't define them

CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(podder VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

configure_file(config.h.in config.h ESCAPE_QUOTES)
```

config.h.in

```cpp
#ifndef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#define HAVE_CONFIG_H

#cmakedefine ${CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION}

#endif
```

And the generated config.h looks like this

```cpp
#ifndef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#define HAVE_CONFIG_H

/* #undef  */

#endif
```

Comment: What if you used `#cmakedefine CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION` instead?

Comment: Also, the variable is [`PROJECT_VERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_VERSION.html), not `CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION`.

Comment: As far as I know (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION.html)[CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION] works too

Comment: Using PROJECT_VERSION makes no difference and ```#cmakedefine CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION``` just produces ```#define CMAKE_PROJECT_VERSION```

Comment: how about `#cmakedefine ${PROJECT_VERSION}`?

Comment: @VTT Still makes no difference

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

```
#ifndef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#define HAVE_CONFIG_H

#cmakedefine PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}

#endif
```

The syntax is `#cmakedefine VAR ...` where `VAR`is the variable name (without `$()`) and the expression `...` is evaluated, see [configure_file()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html). If the variable `VAR` is not defined or evaluates to false it is replaced by `/* #undef VAR */`.